# Why are Elves so much lighter than other races

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, elves

While the fellowship is trying to make for the pass of the Redhorn Gate, during Book 2 Chapter 3, why is it that Legolas seems so much lighter than his companions of other race?  Are elves actually physically lighter than others or is it just one of the many graces given to the Eldar by Eru?

> With that he sprang forth nimbly, and then Frodo noticed as if for the first
>   time, though he had long known it, that the Elf had no boots, but wore only
>   light shoes, as he always did, and his feet made little imprint in the snow.

As a side note, my brothers and I used to always joke that the reason Legolas was so light on his feet was because elves are hollow-boned, but I seriously doubt that that's the actual reason.

Comment: It isn't necessarily just the weight. It could also be: magic in the shoes; or skill (I'm personally able to walk on some of the snow where most normal people of the same wight sink. Comes from LOTS of practice, and special ways to place your foot and your weight).

Comment: @DVK I love doing that. It works especially well if there is a thin layer of ice on top of the snow. You can walk across it without breaking through by not putting enough pressure on any one point for long enough to break it.

Comment: I took Ninjutsu in college, and one of the exercises in the second level class was walking on rice paper without tearing it. It's way harder than you'd think (I never could do it), but the instructor could do it seemingly with ease.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because the other question shows that it's a misunderstanding that Elves are lighter; they're not; they just have special skill at this kind of thing.

Comment: Answer:  They aren't.  They're just magical and stuff.

Comment: @Omegacron - I feel deprived.  I went to 4 different colleges and none of them offered courses in ninjutsu.

Comment: @WadCheber it was listed on the schedule as Karate, but the instructor told us after the fact that what he had a belt in - and therefore what he would be teaching - was actually Bujinkan Ninjutsu. Very cool classes - the teacher was taught by one of Stephen Hayes' students.